# Dynamic Columns in View Based on Table Content

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying to search for the solution to this for a while now, but I must not know the right terminology.  Below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Given these three tables:

Table: thing

```
| id | name | 
-------------
| 1  | Foo  |
| 2  | Bar  |
| 3  | Baz  |
```

Table: issue

```
| id | title  |
---------------
| 1  | Crazy  |
| 2  | Stupid |
| 3  | Ugly   |
```

Table: thing_issue

```
| id | thing_id | issue_id |
----------------------------
| 1  | 1        | 1        |
| 2  | 1        | 2        |
| 3  | 1        | 3        |
| 4  | 2        | 2        |
| 5  | 3        | 1        |
| 6  | 3        | 3        |
```

I would like to have a view that produces the following:

```
| Thing ID | Thing Name | Crazy | Stupid | Ugly |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1        | Foo        | Yes   | Yes    | Yes  |
| 2        | Bar        | No    | Yes    | No   |
| 3        | Baz        | Yes   | No     | Yes  |
```

The tricky part is that I want the columns on the end to be dynamic based on the content of the `issue` table.  Meaning, if the `issue` table had a row inserted thusly:

Table: issue

```
| id | title  |
---------------
| 1  | Crazy  |
| 2  | Stupid |
| 3  | Ugly   |
| 4  | Mad    |
```

Then the output of the view would then be as follows (without making any modifications to the view):

```
| Thing ID | Thing Name | Crazy | Stupid | Ugly | Mad |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1        | Foo        | Yes   | Yes    | Yes  | No  |
| 2        | Bar        | No    | Yes    | No   | No  |
| 3        | Baz        | Yes   | No     | Yes  | No  |
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.  Any help would be greatly apprecheated!

Comment: many-times dup… search SO for "pivot" or "crosstab" and check this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: @Denis Unless I'm missing something that does not address the dynamic column requirements for the view.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Join the tables to put them in the expected input format, and let crosstab take it from there.

Comment: @Denis The `crosstab()` documentation states "The crosstab function is declared to return setof record, so the actual names and types of the output columns must be defined in the FROM clause of the calling SELECT statement..."  How will that work when the output columns are dynamic based on the contents of the `issue` table?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=postgresql+crosstab+dynamic+column+stackoverflow

Comment: There is no way with Postgres to have dynamic column names using crosstab without defining the column names prior to running the query.

There are numerous posts on this exact question and it seems the the dynamic columns names is possible. I spent 1 hour reading up on it was I was curious to solve the problem.